# Django - Product title not showing in cart page

Tags: django, ajax

I'm having trouble getting the product title to show in the cart page after its added to cart. It shows everything except the Title of the product.

**cart.py**

```
    def __len__(self):
        return sum(item["qty"] for item in self.cart.values()) 



    def __iter__(self):

        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        cart = self.cart.copy()

        for product in products:
            cart[str(product.id)]["product"] = product

        for item in cart.values():
            item["price"] = Decimal(item["price"])
            item["total_price"] = item["price"] * item["qty"]
            yield item
```

cart.py

```
def front_page(request):
    cart = Cart(request)

    return render(request, 'cart/front_page.html', {
            
            'cart':cart
            
        })
```

cart_details.html

This is all the issue starts, it shows everything else like qty and price for each added item but not the product name.

```
      {% for item in cart %}
      {% with product=item.product %}
      <div class="" data-index="{{product.id}}">
        <div class="row g-0">
          <div class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block">
            {% for image in product.product_image.all %}
            {% if image.is_feature%}
            <img class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt="{{ image.image.alt_text }}">
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-10 ps-md-3">
            <div class="card-body p-1">
              <a class="" href="{{item.product.get_absolute_url}}">
                <p class="card-text pb-3">{{product.title}}</p>
              </a>
              <label for="select">Qty</label>
              <select id="select{{product.id}}" style="width:50px;height:31px;">
                <option value="" selected disabled hidden>{{item.qty}}</option>
                <option value="">1</option>
                <option value="">2</option>
                <option value="">3</option>
                <option value="">4</option>
              </select>
              <a type="button" id="update-button" data-index="{{product.id}}"
                class="update-button text-decoration-none small ps-3">Update</a>
              <a type="button" id="delete-button" data-index="{{product.id}}"
                class="delete-button text-decoration-none small">Delete</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endwith %}
      {% endfor %}
```

ajax

```
  <script>
    $(document).on('click', '#add_button', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url "inventory:single_product_add_to_cart" %}',
        data: {
          productid: $('#add_button').val(),
          productqty: $('#select option:selected').text(),
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{csrf_token}}",
          action: 'post'
        },
        success: function (json) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {}
      });
    })
  </script>
```

What may be causing this?

Comment: try using ```item.product.title```?

Comment: not working-thank you though